# Update the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) to WSL 2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a list of instructions to follow but when I get to step 6 I'm met with

> There is no distribution with the supplied name.

Can someone please lead me in the right direction please? Thse are the steps I am trying to follow

> 1. Search for the "Command Prompt" application using the "Start" menu
> 2. Select "Run as administrator" from the right side of the search window
> 3. Allow the program to make changes to your device and wait for the "Command Prompt" application to open
> 4. Type `wsl --set-default-version 2` into the terminal and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
>
>    (Note: you should see a message starting with "For information on
>    key differences…")
> 5. Type `wsl --status` into the terminal and press .
>
>    You should see a message including "Default Version 2", which
>    verifies that the default version has been set correctly.
> 6. Type `wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2` into the terminal and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
> 7. Wait for the "Conversion complete" or "This distribution is already the requested version" message in the terminal
> 8. Type `wsl --list --verbose` into the terminal and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
>
> You should see a message including "NAME Ubuntu VERSION 2", which
> verifies that the default version has been set correctly

.

Comment: There are [three versions of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-on-wsl2-on-windows-10#3-download-ubuntu) in the Store. I'd recommend you use the Ubuntu command line install shown there to make sure you got the correct version for your guide installed.

Comment: @PasWei Actually 4 for the next 6 months.  Ubuntu, Ubuntu-18.04, Ubuntu-20.04, and now Ubuntu-22.04.  The 18.04 release will be removed in April of 2023 when it reaches end-of-support.

Comment: @user1737305 If the steps in the answer I provided don't work, then please include the output of `wsl -l -v` in an edit to your question.  Thanks!

Comment: There are only two different versions (based on the Ubuntu page, which is 2 years out of date).  Ubuntu listing will always be the current version. There are more versions, if you include the preview version, and the versions the page left out.

Comment: @Ramhound Right - Forgot about the Preview - That makes 5.

Answer (score 11):

Steps 6 and 8 are a bit reversed, IMHO.

Let's try a different way, starting with Step 6:

6. Type `wsl -l -v`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and confirm the name of the distribution you are using.  Replace "Ubuntu" in the steps below with the actual name of the distribution.  This may be, for example, `Ubuntu-22.04` (or another version).
7. Type `wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2` (or the distribution name) into the terminal and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
8. Wait for the "Conversion complete" or "This distribution is already the requested version" message in the terminal
9. Type `wsl -l -v` into the terminal and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
10. Confirm that the distribution is set to version 2.